# Is it required to provide a detailed itinerary for Schengen visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, india, schengen-visas

Is it required to give a detailed itinerary like [this](https://www.thepoortraveler.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Schengen-Visa-France-Itinerary.pdf) for a Schengen Visa application?

Or is it enough to provide a basic itinerary like this?

```
1-June to 3-June in Rome
3-June to 6-June in Milan
6-June to 10-June in Zurich
```

I don't see any requirement asking for a "detailed" itinerary as per the [documents required](http://www.vfs-italy.co.in/mumbai/pdf/Tourist-Visa-Application-Arrangement.pdf).

Can someone guide me here?

Comment: I like how the sample itinerary you link to proposes a _day tour to New Zealand_ from Copenhagen. (Yes, they're probably going to _Nordsjælland_ and _Kronborg_ castle).

Comment: @HenningMakholm It's a sample itinerary, and I think they meant *North Zealand and Hamlet castle*.

Comment: x @Parthapratim, there is no such thing as "Hamlet castle", except in the fever-addled imaginations of tourist marketers.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Aah! I see. I just got the name from [this](https://www.viator.com/tours/Copenhagen/Castles-Tour-from-Copenhagen-North-Zealand-and-Hamlet-Castle/d463-2158DKAP006) link.

Answer (score 2):

A basic itinerary should suffice and has for my partner getting a Visa in the past. Though we had supporting documentation for at least a portion of the itinerary such as train tickets, invitation letter and booked accommodation.

Please note that how the rules are interpreted varies a great deal between the nation states that make up the Schengen area, and between the different embassies. For example the Spanish embassy in Edinburgh was notorious for demanding further details and/or interviews before granting a basic Visa that would only just cover the itinerary. We applied to the German embassy and got a her a 6 month visa with multiple entries.

Ideally find someone who has applied at the same embassy to get some information about how they are applying the rules at that site. Or failing that you might find something in google reviews pertaining to the embassy.